# Woocommerce Product Vendors change "sold by"

Tags: php, wordpress

If anyone is familiar with the Woocommerce Product Vendors plugin, I'm trying to do something that I thought would be fairly simple. I'm not highly proficient in PHP but can wrap my head around some of it.

I'm trying to change where the output says, "Sold by `vendorname`". All I want to do is change "Sold by" to something else.

I changed it in the code, knowing that if there was an update, my change would go away. So, I'm assuming I need to put it in my Child Theme functions.php file. That's where I'm stuck.

Help greatly appreciate.

Answer (score 3):

Dug around the code and look at some additional documentation to give me some inspiration. I was able to update the text in functions.php file with the following:

```
/* update vendor sold by text */
add_filter( 'wcpv_sold_by_text', 'sold_by_text' );
function sold_by_text() {
  return 'Artist:';
}
```